# React.js как сделать поиск(фильтр) по имени или адресу

Tags: reactjs

Я новичок в работе с React.js, пытаюсь сделать фильтр но столкнулся с рядом проблем, буду благодарен если подскажи как это можно сделать. Есть основной компонент Speakers.js в котором я получаю json а затем отправляю это во внутренние компоненты List и Filter. В List я вывожу весь список спикеров(который приходит в Json). В Filter при вводе поле name или address а затем при нажатии на кнопку search должен происходить поиск.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Speakers.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Filters from './Filters';
import List from './List';

class Speakers extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
            items: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({isLoading: true});
        fetch("https://randomapi.com/api/6de6abfedb24f889e0b5f675edc50deb?fmt=raw&sole")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        items: result,
                        isLoading: false
                    });
                    console.log(result);
                }
            )
            .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="speakers">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <Filters getItems={this.state} />
                    <List getItems={this.state} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Speakers;
```

List.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class List extends Component {
    render() {
        const {items, isLoading} = this.props.getItems;
        if (isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading ...</p>;
        } 

        return (
            <div className="speakers__list">
                <div className="row">
                    {items.map((item, index) => (
                        <div className="col-md-3" key={index}>
                            <div className="card form-group shadow">
                                <div className="card-body text-center">
                                    <h5 className="card-title">{item.first} {item.last}</h5>
                                    <p>{item.email}</p>
                                    <p>{item.address}</p>
                                    <p>{item.balance}</p>
                                    <p>{item.created}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default List;
```

Filters.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Filters extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="filters">
                <div className="alert shadow">
                    <form>
                        <div className="container-fluid">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-5">
                                    <label>Name/Surname</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control" />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-5">
                                    <label>Address</label>
                                    <input type="text" className="form-control"/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-2 align-self-center text-center">
                                    <button className="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Filters;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно настроить обмен данными между двумя компонентами (`List` и `Filter`), которые связаны только родителем(`Speakers`). Проще всего связать их через него:

Заводим поле `name` и `address` в стейте. И хендлеры:

```
_handleAddressChange = value => this.setState({address: value})
_handleNameChange = value => this.setState({name: value})
```

Далее пробрасываем все это в наш `Filter`:

```
<Filters 
  name={this.state.name} 
  address={this.state.address} 
  onNameChange={this._handleAdressChange} 
  onAddressChange={this._handleAddressChange} 
/>
```

В нем расставляем все по своим местам, так, чтобы когда мы писали в инпут, его данные попадали в стейт `Speakers`. И фильтруем данные как нам надо:

```
<List getItems={this.state.items.filter(({name, address}) => this.state.name === name || this.state.address === address)} />
```

PS Такие действия чаще делаются через `redux` или `mobx`

Comment: подскажите а в List нужно делать какие это изменения в функции {items.map((item, index) => ... сейчас просто ошибка возникает TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: вот такая ошибка http://joxi.ru/nAypZqPHYvW072

Comment: Попробуйте так {items && items.map((item, index) => ... }

Если данные приходят с сервера то в переменой items ничего нету пока сервер не пришлет ответ.